# Copy and pasting from worksheet A to worksheet B (Value only)

Tags: powershell

I am currently trying to copy value from a range A1:L12 and paste the values on worksheet B with pastespecial, but I am running into an error.

"Unable to get the PasteSpecial property of the Worksheet class"

```
#Add New Worksheet

$WorkSheettwo = $WorkBook.worksheets.add()
$WorkSheettwo.name = "Final_Copy"

$WorkSheet.Range("test_camp!A1:L12").Copy()
$WorkSheettwo.Range("Final_Copy!A1:L12").Select()
$WorkSheettwo.PasteSpecial(-4163)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

```
#Add New Worksheet

$WorkSheettwo = $WorkBook.worksheets.add()
$WorkSheettwo.name = "Final_Copy"

$WorkSheet.Range("test_camp!A1:L12").Copy()
$RangeAp = $WorkSheettwo.Range("Final_Copy!A1:L12")
$RangeAp.PasteSpecial(-4163)
```